# View design not showing in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistackview

I'm trying to create a `UIView` and set it as a `ViewController's` view.
I did set it up but it won't show properly. for example, I chose a `backgroundColor` for the view, which is not showing. I added two buttons and they do show, but not as expected.
This is my `UIView` code:

```
import UIKit

public final class LoginView: UIView {
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(stackView)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.appColors.white

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
    ])
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

public let login: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17.0)
    button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.appColors.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.appColors.green
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    button.clipsToBounds = true

    return button
}()

public let signup: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17.0)
    button.setTitle("Signup", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.appColors.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.appColors.red
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    button.clipsToBounds = true

    return button
}()

private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.login, self.signup])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 10.0
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return stackView
}()
}
```

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class loginVC: UIViewController {
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view = LoginVC()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


}
```

As you can see, I did set up everything, and I did changed the look of the buttons and chose a backgorund color, but it just won't show on the `ViewController`.
I want to seperate the `View` and the `ViewController` because I really need flexability with this app, but it just won't work.
Any ideas?[image]

Comment: In `self.view = loginVC()`, should not it be, `self.view =  LoginView()` ?

Comment: It is, I just changed it and forgot to update. I will now.

Comment: Hii i change background color to black your uiview background is change in whole screen is it right ?

Comment: Please check your UIColor code.? i only change colors except all same and it's working for me

Comment: You have to done this thing in didLoad()

Comment: @YogeshPatel I would have never thought about that. I thought the my UIColor is working perfectly, and this it the problem it didn't. a million thanks!

Comment: Don't call `super.loadView()`, as recommended by Apple.

Comment: Yeah Great it's working for you happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `loadView()`, it must be `LoginView()` instead of `loginVC()`, i.e

```
class loginVC: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.view = LoginView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Try replacing `UIColor.appColors` with just `UIColor` and see if it giving the expected result. This is the only thing I changed in your code to get that working perfectly.

Comment: It is, I changed it already but still the same thing happens.

Comment: I'm getting the result as in screenshot. Is something else expected?

Comment: Nope, This is what I wanna get, but it does not work.

Comment: Check the appColors you're using. That is the only thing I changed in your code.

Comment: Try use `self.view = LoginVC()` on `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Try replacing `UIColor.appColors` with just `UIColor` and see if it giving the expected result.

Comment: @Augusto You don't set the controller's view in viewDidLoad(). Apple has provided a separate method for that - loadView().

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I can't see reasons to it not works.

Comment: Thanks! The appsColor was the problem.